# Getting output from DxDiag in C#

Tags: c#

So I am trying to automate the output from DxDiag in C# and I have run into a problem. The program runs but doesn't produce any output file. It might be that I am not passing parameters correctly or that I am misunderstanding something.

When running DxDiag in the normal command line I do this and it works as expected:

```
dxdiag -64bit -x C:\dxFromCode.xml
```

And this is how I am trying to do it in code:

```
//Create process
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "dxdiag";

pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"64bit x C:\dxFromCode.xml";

pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

//Set output of program to be written to process output stream
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

//Start the process
pProcess.Start();

//Wait for process to finish
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

EDIT:

Ok, so I changed my code to build for x64. This makes dxdiag automatically start the as the 64-bit version. Then I could just take away the 64bit switch and suddenly everything works as I would expect.

Comment: Well, don't use `x` instead of `/x`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. I have tried with /x and -x.

Comment: .. and how about `-64bits` which is without `-`?

Comment: Don't make up your own switches either, `64bit` doesn't mean anything.  If you want to run the 64-bit version of dxdiag from a 32-bit program then you'll have to use c:\windows\sysnative\dxdiag.exe

Comment: 64bit is a valid switch: http://windowcmc.com/q.php?q=dxdiag-manual

Comment: It is not a valid switch for the 64-bit version.  Get this running from the command prompt first before you try to run it from code.

Comment: it does run from the command prompt. And If you run with just the 64bit switch you can see that It does make a difference. Try it yourself @HansPassant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DxDiag is quite cranky on a 64-bit OS.  The 32-bit version and the 64-bit version accept different command line switches and it doesn't give a peep when you use the wrong one.  The /x option simply does not work when you try to use the /64bit option on the 32-bit version.  And the 64-bit version does not accept /64bit.  You'll have to start the 64-bit version explicitly when you run on a 64-bit OS and your program runs in 32-bit mode.

This worked well on my Win81 x64 machine:

```
    private string RunDxDiag() {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4 && Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
            // Need to run the 64-bit version
            psi.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
                "sysnative\\dxdiag.exe");
        }
        else {
            // Okay with the native version
            psi.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Environment.SystemDirectory, 
                "dxdiag.exe");
        }
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        try {
            psi.Arguments = "/x " + path;
            using (var prc = Process.Start(psi)) {
                prc.WaitForExit();
                if (prc.ExitCode != 0) {
                    throw new Exception("DXDIAG failed with exit code " + prc.ExitCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
        finally {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding /user:Administrator cmd /K to the arguments statement. Like this:

```
Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /K " + command + "\""
```

Command being `64bit x C:\dxFromCode.xml`. I think your problem might be that you need to run cmd as Administrator.

Comment: Hm...this just gave me a warning from DxDiag that I am not sending valid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, Hans's code didn't work for me. I found that the `WaitForExit(`) call would return before the file could be read. As a workaround, I added this:

```
int nTries = 0;
do
{
  string szText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
  if (szText.Length != 0)
  {
    return szText;
  }
  else
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
} while (nTries++ < 10);
return "";
```