# Process.WaitForExit() doesn't wait for log creation when trying to get log from DxDiag

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

So i am using c# (.net 4.0) version and trying to run DxDiag to get the log.

I tried to use anwer in this question: [Getting output from DxDiag in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189656/getting-output-from-dxdiag-in-c-sharp)

But it looks like prc.WaitForExit() quits immediatelly and when trying to read log file it is empty (because it is made after 4-5 seconds).
I was using psi.UseShellExecute = true and false and both results was the same.

Also if I checked:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("dxdiag");
```

The pname process id was different than id from prc.Start().

It looks like process (dxdiag) is starting, immediately closing and another one is starting and doing the log file. 
Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using Process Explorer and Process Monitor to see what is created, opened, closed and written to, and at what point? That would be the first thing I would do.

Comment: The Windows version matters.  Iirc, the 32-bit version of dxdiag.exe will start the 64-bit version and terminate.  So a simple workaround is right-clicking your project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = AnyCPU, Prefer 32-bit off.

Comment: @HansPassant - i have this project properties from the beggining and the problem still occurs. \nBaldrick - thx for the tip. I will check this out but it's probably like HansPassant said (32 bit DxDiag runs 64 bit DxDiag)